# I can't get authenticated with my api using django

Tags: python, django, curl, pycharm

I am trying to make curl requests to my api server that I have secured by this:[image: My security]

I then use the ubuntu app for windows the following way:

> curl http://127.0.0.1:8000/orbitalelements/ -X POST -H 'Authorization: Token 5894b35af2dde31c2d271a9348901312d3cbe348' -H 'Content-Type:application/json' -d '{"Object":"bs", "Epoch": "49400", "TP":"1", "e":"1
> ", "I":"1", "w":"1", "Node":"1", "q":"1", "QL":"1", "P":"1", "MOID":"1", "ref":"bs", "object_name":"bs"}'

The token I use here is in the database:
[image: database token]

However I can't get it to accept the token:
[image: Can't get in]

Does anyone know why this isn't working?

Here is the github: https://github.com/DieterClaessens67/SOA

Comment: hier een upvote om je question te helpen ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out I had to add

```
 rest_framework.authtoken,
```

to installed apps in djangoProject1 settings.py and
a new line with

```
> REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
    ],
}
```

too.